# Combining Rate of Winning | Multiplication or Addition

Tags: probability, game-theory, independence, percentages, lotteries

**Problem**
Imagine I play the lottery and have a $2\%$ rate of winning. My friend also plays the lottery and has a $1\%$ rate of winning. Whoever wins, we will share the prize.

- We could think our chances are $3\%$ then.
- But let's think on the other side. My $2\%$ chance of winning also are $98\%$ chance of losing, which is $0.98$. For my friend, that losing rate is $99\%$ which is $0.99$. If I multiply our chance of NOT winning, that's $0.9702$. This can be converted to $2.98\%$ chance of winning.

So, are our chances of winning are $3\%$ or $2.98\%?$

Comment: See how much you can mathematize everything you've written. For example, why should it be true that "our chances" are $3$ percent? If I have a $90$%  chance of doing something and my sister has an $85$% chance of doing the same thing, surely the chances of one of us doing it isn't $90+85 = 175$% , right? Your thinking for the second part seems okay : the answer is very much $2.98$ (under the assumption that you and your friends success are independent, which I'm surprised they are but I'll leave that to technicalities of design).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer It makes sense. So 2% and 1% are 0.02 and 0.01. How am I supposed to get that 0.0298 (2.98%) without doing that whole "chances of not winning" process ?

Comment: It depends on whether you and your friend can simultaneously win.  If not, then it is $3\%$.  Alternatively, if your attempt to win, and your friends attempt to win are *independent events* then it is $2.98\%$.  Here, the phrase independent events signifies that your friend's probability of winning is in no way affected by whether you win.

Comment: That's the second scenario. Let's say they are a lot of prizes ! :)
How do I get to 0.0298 from 0.02 and 0.01 ?

Comment: I understand what you means by independent events. Thanks that is clearer for me now between that 3% and 2.98% confusion :)

Comment: @Will Unfortunately you will always need to do that. See David's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is the event that you win, and $B$ is the event that your friend wins,
then $A\cup B$ is the event that you share at least one prize,
and $A\cap B$ is the event that you both win the lottery (so you share two prizes).

Using $P(A)$ for the probability that the event $A$ happens,
$P(B)$ for the probability that $B$ happens, etc,

$$ P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B). $$

If you and your friend are able to compare plans before you play and make sure you never play the same numbers, then you will never win two prizes simultaneously.
That is, in that case $P(A\cap B) = 0$ and the probability that at least one of you wins a prize is actually $3\%.$

However, if you and your friend play completely independently with no mutual planning, it is reasonable to suppose that your chances of winning are completely independent.
That is, it is reasonable to suppose that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B).$
(This is the definition of what it means for events to be independent.)
In that case
$$ P(A\cap B) = 0.02 \cdot 0.01 = 0.0002 $$
(writing all the percentage probabilities in non-percentage decimal format, such as $0.02$ instead of $2\%$, so that we don't get confused about how to multiply $2\% \times 1\%$),
and therefore
$$ P(A\cup B) = 0.02 + 0.01 - 0.0002 = 0.0298, $$
which is $2.98\%.$